# How to change a model field based on certain period of time using Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to make some changes in my model automatically. Here, after a new order is placed I want to update the order status to cancel if isPaid not become true in 1 day of the order placed. how can I do this?

```
class Order(models.Model):

    PENDING_PAYMENT = 'PENDING_PAYMENT'

    status_choices = [

        ('CANCEL', 'Cancel'),
        ('PENDING_PAYMENT', 'Pending Payment'),
        ('ON_HOLD', 'On Hold'),
        ('WAITING_FOR_PAYMENT', 'Waiting For Payment'),
        ('PROCESSING', 'Processing'),
        ('DONE', 'Done'),

    ]

    Ordinary = 'Ordinary'

    customer_choices = [

        ('Ordinary', 'Ordinary'),
        ('Police', 'Police'),
        ('RAB', 'RAB'),
        ('DGIF', 'DGIF'),
        ('CID', 'CID'),
        ('NAVY', 'NAVY'),
        ('Air Force', 'Air Force'),
        ('Army', 'Army'),
        ('DB', 'DB'),
        ('Administration', 'Administration'),

    ]

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    paymentMethod = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    taxPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    shippingPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    totalPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    isPaid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    paidAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    isDelivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deliverAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True, blank=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=220, choices=status_choices, default=PENDING_PAYMENT)
    customerType = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, choices=customer_choices, default=Ordinary)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a periodically check against orders to update the status. You can use cron, check this [package](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron).

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, you need to execute periodically a function that check if the actual date - the date on witch a order has been placed (created) > 1 day, then change the status to 'cancel'.

**1) Use django-cellery** : [django-celery](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery/) provides Celery integration for Django. You will be able to run task (function) periodically.

**2) The function to run periodically**
Here is an example of task/function you can run to check

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from your_app.models import Order

def cancel_order():
    # Retrieve the pending orders
    pending_orders = Order.objects.filter(status='PENDING_PAYMENT')
    # Loop and cancel unpaid order > 1 day
    for order in pending_orders:
        # if the time today is greater than order created date + 1 day
        if datetime.today() > (order.createdAt + timedelta(days=1)):
            order.status = 'CANCEL'
            order.save()
            # You can also write this action in a log file too
```

Comment: Can I do this in this way?

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if datetime.today() > (self.createdAt + timedelta(days=1)):
            if self.paidAt != True:
                self.orderStatus = 'Cancel'
                return super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: The **save()** method only executes at two times. when **creating** and **modifying** the object. And don't run periodically as you want. Use [django-cron](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) or [django-celery](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery/) to do this repeated task.

Comment: Yes i used apscheduler and it is working. First I tried django-cron but I got error because of using windows man, there is one package that is not available in windows

Comment: You can up-vote my answer, or mark it as it resolve your issue ;-)

Comment: what does order.createdAt represent? a field in your model? @Rvector please your response is needed.

Comment: @oriohac order is an instance of an Order Model.
order.createdAt is a field : DatetimeField or DateField in the django Order nodel.

Comment: @Rvector Now  understand,  wonder why I didn't then.